# fixed footer loaded from external js does "overlap" sitecontent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

i'm having a div with `position:fixed; height:100px;width:100%; bottom:0;` which is loaded from an external .js file (`document.write("...");`) (external server).

I'm facing the problem that the `position:fixed` div always overlaps the remaining 100px of the site where the external .js is implemented. Is there any css/js workaround to fix that issue? All modifications have to be done in that external .js file as i cant access the sourcecode of the site(s) itself, they just loads the external javascript file.

Comment: Could you add padding-bottom: 100px or margin-bottom: 100px to your body css to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

adjust the body's bottom padding by `100px`

```
$('body').css('padding-bottom', '100px')
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt work with padding-bottom - i've now tried to fix it that way: `function getDocHeight() {
    var D = document;
    return Math.max(
        Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
        Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
    );
}
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.height=(getDocHeight()+177)+"px";` and it seems to work - but i'm not sure if its the easiest solution ;)

Comment: where is the `177` coming from?

Comment: sorry, the actual height of the fixed div is 187 - for some strange reason i just have to add 177 to get the correct spacing on the bottom of the document.

Comment: `$('body').css('padding-bottom', '177px')` would probably work as well then, or `$('body').height($('body').height() + 177)`